# Capitalizing the first letter of every word in a string and preforming a word count

Tags: c, string, function

Beginner here learning C.
I need to input a paragraph of text and then write two functions.

the first function capitalizes every first letter of the text. (This Is An Example)

the second function needs to count all the words in the paragraph.

First step I am taking is inputing the paragraph, I started by just adding the first two sentences. How do I format this paragraph into this string without writing it all on one line? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
int main (void)
{

char prose[] = "She should have died hereafter;
                There would have been a time for such a word.";

printf("%s\n",prose);




return 0;
}
```

This is the while loop I am trying to use to detect where the non alphabetic symbols are.

```
while (prose[i])
{
    if (isalpha(prose[i]))
        printf("%c is alpha\n",prose[i]);
             else

                 printf("%c is not alpha\n",prose[i]);
                i++;

        }
```

Any help on where to move from here?

Comment: 0) walk the string 1) detect the first letter of a word (Hint: it is a letter, and the preceding character is **not** a letter) 2) change it to uppercase. 3) the second function now comes naturally.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you for your response. What exactly do you mean by "walk the string"? I take it as I should use a while loop to find out when there is no character present (like searching for the NULL?). I'm having a hard time trying to put that into code. Then I figured I would add 32 to the value of the first letter making it become a uppercase letter. Any advice on how I should word that while loop? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Adjacent string literals in C are concatenated into a single string, so you can easily split it across lines like this:

```
char prose[] = "She should have died hereafter;\n"
               "There would have been a time for such a word.";
```

(Eventually you might want to read the prose from a file or perhaps `stdin`, instead of hard-coding it into your program.)

To capitalize letters, iterate through the string one character at a time and capitalize every alphabet letter if the previous character was not an alphabet letter (or whatever your criterion is). See `ctype.h` for helpful functions.

For counting words, you can do something similar, but instead of modifying the string you just increment a counter every time you hit a new word.

In both cases check that your code handles the first and last words correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this response. So far I am using the function isalpha in ctype.h to determine whether or not the character is alphabetic. How do you tell the program to to go to the next character in the string to change it to an uppercase? For instance, isalpha determines the space is not alphabetic, how do I tell it to look one character past the space and then raise it to an uppercase? Been on this question for hours, probably embarrassing myself.

Comment: @user2990129 Well, for example, use a variable to store whether or not the previous character was alphabetic (start from false). Then when you find an alphabetic character and the previous was not alphabetic, then uppercase the current character.

Comment: forgive me for asking so many questions. Is there a way I can show you the code I have so far? I am new to C and I am new to stack overflow, your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @user2990129 Ask a new question here if you need help with something else, and put the relevant code into that question.

Comment: @user2990129 You seem to be off to a reasonable start; work on proper indenting and enclose the then and else blocks in `{}`, then just do what I said previously (i.e., set a variable to remember whether or not the previous character was alphabetic, if it wasn't but the current char is, then you are at the start of a word).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this:

```
    char prose[] = "\
She should have died hereafter.\n\
There would have been a time for such a word.\n\
";
    printf("%s\n",prose);
```

`\n` is for an actual new line in the string, `\` at the end of line lets the statement continue on the next line.

Comment: Yes, line continuation with backslashes works as an alternative to what I proposed in my answer. Personally I never liked that style, however, since it breaks indentation.

Comment: @Arkku You got a good point. But I think it's a matter of personal preference. Two adjacent strings over two separate lines may help indentation, but the second string looks isolated.

Comment: I don't think it looks very isolated when it's indented to the same level (especially when there are more than two), but of course it is possible to combine both the separate string literals and still place the (superfluous) \ at the end of the line to signify continuation.

Comment: @Arkku OK, how about this: You type less when you use backslash. Especially less shift keys. =D

Comment: Using the escape char method is a) ugly ugly ugly and b) easily broken by someone (or an editor) accidentally adding whitespace after the escape char.  I'm pretty sure this situation is exactly why the C standard concatenates adjacent strings in the first place.  It was to fix a hideous ugliness.

Comment: @Carey I already said it's personal preference. I think lots of quotes are uglier and abuses your fingers. And modern compilers are ok with spaces after the backslash (just warning at most). And I think the more important purpose of concatenating adjacent strings is to make it easy to use macros with literal strings. e.g. full_path = BASE_PATH "/subdir/filename";